# Failed to get mock metadata (babel 7 upgrade)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I am mocking out a git submodule (which is essentially just a javascript library we use at work), and all my mocks started returning:

`Failed to get mock metadata`

This happened after we upgraded the git submodule project to babel 7 (from 6). If I go into the submodule and revert the changes back to babel 6 the tests return to passing.

I mock out the module like so:

```
// path is an alias defined in webpack config
import { MyModule } from 'my-module';

jest.mock('my-module');

MyModule.someAttr.mockResolvedValue({data});
```

Any ideas why upgrading to babel 7 introduced these errors, everything else (including the submodule) works fine, just the tests on our UI which utilizes the submodule don't pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to the way Jest resolves [manual mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks). It may be that the import statement is resolved by Webpack with the alias resolver, but the `jest.mock()` function would not have that alias resolver into consideration. Manual mocks are resolved in the `__mocks__/` folders relative to the

Because your mock module is part of a git submodule. You could either set up your submodule directory to be placed in the root of your project inside a `__mocks__/` folder or either have the exported module of your submodule dependency inside a `__mocks__/` folder.

```
.
├── config
├── __mocks__
│   └── mock-module.js
├── submodule
│   ├── __mocks__
│   │   └── mock-submodule.js
│   └── index.js
├── node_modules
└── src
```

Comment: When you say a relative directory, that means inside of the submodule correct? Is it possible to just place a __mocks__ dir at the root level of my project since putting it inside of a submodule seems strange?

Comment: I just updated my answer, you could have the mock in your project root or in your submodule root.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `jest.mock('my-module');` from my code worked. I've faced this error for `vue3-lottie` package.